# How To Change ImageView drawable For A Single RecyclerView Row

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-drawable

I am not particularly sure how to ask this question, so I will just use images to explain

[image] [image]

In my App, onClick of the download icon calls a download method for the video in the row. When it is completely downloaded, the Icon changes from black to green. A boolean flag is used to save this state in SharedPreference. This saved state is called again in my RecyclerView Adapter so the downloaded state can reflect when the app is relaunched.

THE CHALLENGE IS...

When the app relaunches, instead only the downloaded row icon to show green, the Icon turns green for every row even when they have not been downloaded. below is my code.

```
class DownloadReceiver extends ResultReceiver { //DownloadReceiver class
                public DownloadReceiver(Handler handler) {
                    super(handler);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                    super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
                    if (resultCode == TichaDownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                        int progress = resultData.getInt("progress"); //get the progress
                        //Set the progress to progressBarCir
                        progressBarCir.setProgress(progress);
                        icon_download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        progressBarCir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Log.i("STATUS", "DOWNLOADING>>>");
                        if (progress == 100) { // Downloade process is completed
                            isNotDownloaded = false; // Flagging that the video has been downloaded
                            progressBarCir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // Setting the Download Icon to reflect the New color state
                            icon_download.setColorFilter(itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.funnygreen));
                            icon_download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            // Saving the boolean flag in SharedPreferece
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("com.example.instagramclone",MODE_PRIVATE);
                            sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isDownloadedState",isNotDownloaded).commit();
                            
                            // Logging of the save state to confirm state is saved.
                            boolean newState= sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isDownloadedState",true);
                            Log.i("STATE XCHANGE", "DOWNLOADED HENCE, "+String.valueOf(newState));

                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i("STATUS", " NOT DOWNLOADING,BOSS");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Below is a snippet of Holder section of my Adapter Class

```
  public LectureClassesHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // Now we ref each custom layout view item using the itemView
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_topic);
        textViewDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_description);
        textViewDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject_duration);
        imageViewDownload = itemView.findViewById(R.id.download);
        textViewUrl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.url_link);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = itemView.getContext().getSharedPreferences("com.example.instagramclone",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        isNotDownloaded = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("isDownloadedState",true);

        if (isNotDownloaded){
            imageViewDownload.setColorFilter(itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            Log.i("DOWNLOAD STATE ","NOT Downloaded State is "+ isNotDownloaded);
        }else {
            imageViewDownload.setColorFilter(itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.funnygreen));
            Log.i("DOWNLOAD STATE ","NOT Downloaded State is "+ isNotDownloaded);
        }

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                    listener.onItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position, itemView);
                }
            }
        });

        // Incase e no work
        imageViewDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && listener != null) {
                    listener.onViewItemClick(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position), position, itemView);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I NEED a way to make the change effective for only the row concerned. Would appreciate any assistance on how to achieve this.

Comment: do you have an issue using a database?

Comment: well, of course this will happen - you're just saving a boolean `isNotDownloaded` but you have no way of associating that value with a particular row. therefore, as soon as `isNotDownloaded` changes it will apply to all rows and not just one row, you should be able to see that from your  `LectureClassesHolder`

Comment: to fix this, you'd need a way of saving (not just) IF something had been downloaded, but also WHAT/WHICH ITEM has been so that you can associate these together

Comment: @a_local_nobody, Your explanation makes a lot of sense, but how do I affect it as you explained?

Comment: so, i don't think shared preferences would work for this because, i'd rather suggest using a database. in order for this to work, you'll have to save a unique identifier for each file that has been downloaded, maybe like the url.

Comment: so every time you download a file, try to save the url of that file into a database or somewhere else. then retrieve that list of downloaded url's and see if the item's url (or unique ID, whatever it is) is inside the list of items already downloaded. if it, show that it's downloaded, else don't

Comment: your current implementation is very close, but because you're only ever saving _one_ value into shared preferences, you can't really keep track of which files have been saved. you'd need a way to keep track of _all_ the files which have been saved

Comment: @a_local_nobody, Thanks. It looks added up already. I will implement it to see how it performs, again thanks.

Comment: can you post your code for the adapter,i got a soluton for you

Comment: this is merely my suggestion and some ideas of how i'd implement it, i'm sure there are other ways of doing it. unfortunately, i don't do any java coding anymore, only kotlin, so hope this gives you some ideas at least. good luck :)

Comment: @Thompsonsparta, I pasted a section of the adapter alongside the question. Perhaps, you can tell me the section of the adapter you want me to post.

Comment: @Eric onBindViewHolder section

Comment: @a_local_nobody, with respect to using a database, I set up and saved the unique titles of all downloads into an SQLite database table. I retrieve the save list of unique titles in recycler view adapter class and pass the same into an ArrayList, then checked against the entry before alternating the drawable of the imageView.   For some reason, the Image drawable won't just alternate. Thought I understood the logic in your explanation, but It's obvious I am missing something. If you wondn't taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there is of course no association between the individual records and what is stored .The best solution would be to use a database with a table containing atleast a column for the download url and another for status,store the records with the desired status (for example use 0 for not downloaded status and 1 for downloaded status ) and update status column of the row with your url after download then you can query to check the status of the record .however a quick fix to your solution while still using shared prefrence would be to store the links in an array and check against that array  see:

```
 public static String all_records(Context act)
{

    SharedPreferences prefs = act.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS_NAME", act.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return prefs.getString("all_records", "[]");
 
 
    
}
 public static void add_download(Activity act,String url)
{
    JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
    try {
    ja=new JSONArray(all_records(act));
        JSONObject jo=new JSONObject();
        jo.put("url",url);
        ja.put(jo);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    SharedPreferences.Editor saver =act.getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFS_NAME", act.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();



    saver.putString("all_records",ja.toString());
    saver.commit();


}
public static boolean is_downloaded(Activity act,String url)
{
    JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
    try {
    ja=new JSONArray(all_records(act));
        for (int i=0;i<ja.length();i++)
        {
            try {
                Log.e("Check ", "" + ja.getJSONObject(i).getString("url") + " Against " + url);
                if (ja.getJSONObject(i).getString("url").equalsIgnoreCase(url)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){}
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return false;
}
```

in this case you would use it like this to when downloading

```
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
                super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
                if (resultCode == TichaDownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                    int progress = resultData.getInt("progress"); //get the progress
                    //Set the progress to progressBarCir
                    progressBarCir.setProgress(progress);
                    icon_download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    progressBarCir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.i("STATUS", "DOWNLOADING>>>");
                    if (progress == 100) { // Downloade process is completed
                        isNotDownloaded = false; // Flagging that the video has been downloaded
                        progressBarCir.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        // Setting the Download Icon to reflect the New color state
                        icon_download.setColorFilter(itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.funnygreen));
                        icon_download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        // Saving the boolean flag in SharedPreferece
                        add_download(/*your context*/,/*your url*/);

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("STATUS", " NOT DOWNLOADING,BOSS");
                }
            }
```

on your recycle view adapter onbindview or wherever you want to get retrieve the status of whether downloaded `call is_downloaded(/*YOUR CONTEXT*/,"YOUR URL");`

Comment: Thomson thank you for this detailed post. It looks like it would work for the case of my app if I were to continue with SharedPreference, but I have decided to use SQLiteDatabase with a column for URL, and status key of On/Off or 0/1 as you stated. I think it's a better approach like you and @a_local_nobody hinted.